# css change from input

Tags: jquery, css, input

I'm trying to have inputs change the style of particular text and submit it to a filemaker server. Works great on IE but not on safari...

```
<select name="NameStyleFontName" id="'.$recordID2.'"  style="width:105px;"
fontatt="font-family" classid="stagename" onchange="fontupdate(this.id, this.name,
this.value, this.fontatt, this.classid)">

function fontupdate(id, name, value, att, cls)
{
    $('#loadres').html('<img src="loading.gif" />');
    $.post('fontupdate.php', {id: id, name: name, value: value})

    $('.'+cls).css(att, value); //this is where it fails.

    $('#loadres').html('<col />');
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably doesn't work in anything but IE.

Most browsers don't support adding arbitrary attributes to the DOM. Since you're using jQuery, you should be able to get at them still using: `$(this).attr('fontattr')` instead of `this.fontattr`, but you should probably rethink the way you're doing this in the first place.

Or perhaps try using `data-*` attributes, which are an HTML5 feature, and intended for purposes like these. See http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/

Comment: function fontupdate()
 {
          var class = $(this).attr('rel');
    var att = $(this).attr('fontatt');
    $('.'+class).css(att, this.value);  
 };
 $('#NameStyleFontName').click(fontupdate);

Comment: No, `$(this.attr('fontatt')` would have to be passed as a parameter to `fontupdate` in the `onchange`. Or you could modify the `fontupdate` function definition to simply accept the element, i.e. `function fontupdate(el) {` and then `onchange="fontupdate(this)"`. You could then use `$(el).attr('fontatt')` in your function body.

Comment: function fontupdate(el)
 {
  $('#loadres').html('<img src="loading.gif" />');
  var att = $(el).attr('fontatt');
  var cls = $(el).attr('classid');
  var id = $(el).attr('id');
  var name = $(el).attr('name');
  var value = $(el).attr('value');
  $.post('fontupdate.php', {id: id, name: name, value: value})
  
  $('.'+cls).css(att, value);
  
  $('#loadres').html('<col />');
 };